# Where in Japan can I buy ear-wax dissolving liquids?

Tags: japan, health

I've been trying to order liquids to dissolve ear wax (technical term "cerumenolytic solutions") while in Japan. I've tried two stores, and while they have devices to physically remove ear wax, they didn't have anything to dissolve it.

How, if possible, do I find liquids to dissolve ear wax while I'm in Japan? If it matters, I'm in the Kansai region.

Comment: Why don't you get your ears cleaned in one of the ear cleaning shops ? Have heard it is a good thing to try.

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us what liquid (brand etc.) you are after? Because I have never heard of anything like that. That doesn't mean it doesn't exist, merely I have never tried to dissolve earwax with liquids before.

Comment: Is this on-topic?

Comment: @fkraiem "how can I do thing X I normally can do in my home country in foreign country Y?" Is travel related, because it's caused by travel, and it's a real practical problem. See, for example, questions on how to use toilets that occur in foreign countries.

Comment: If olive oil is not available, any not spiced up food oil can do, at home we used sun flower oil. Or the oil they sell for baby care, (called Baby Olie, "Baby Oil" in Dutch.)

Comment: To me this is off-topic, because a local could ask the same question, for example if they did not use this type of thing before and recently heard about it. On the other hand, a local living in a country where a certain type of toilets is used will not ask how to use it on the Internet.

Comment: My GP recommended hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: @MadHatter that sounds like someone preferring a natural remedy over a conventional one. Does your GP have a strong skepticism of conventional western medicine in general?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm no.  I'm on several different kinds of prescription medication, all of which are medically necessary for me, all of which were initiated by her.  She's had me off for CT scans, MRIs, and a PET scan in the past when it's been necessary.  I would have no truck with a GP who showed a preference for *alternative therapies*, which is why I listened when she strongly advocated the olive oil.  Makes a mess of the pillow when I leave it in overnight, but otherwise it works for me.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm not at all, I thought it was a very prudent question under the circumstances.

Comment: I can confirm that using (olive) oil is standard advice in several places (if I count correctly I am the third one to mention this?) It will soften solidified earwax to make it easier to remove with water. Nothing fancier is required, it's not an alternative remedy at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maruetsu. They have [hundreds of stores](https://www.maruetsu.co.jp/corporate/pdf/2012_kaishaannai_english.pdf). Look for `油`   `あぶら` `abura`. [Mineral oil, baby oil, glycerin, hydrogen peroxide saline solution](https://www.verywell.com/how-to-remove-ear-wax-1049336) and [water](http://www.cochrane.org/CD004326/ENT_using-ear-drops-to-remove-impacted-ear-wax-is-better-than-no-treatment-but-no-particular-sort-of-drops-can-be-recommended-over-any-other) are other options.

Comment: For future readers, note that Maruetsu is a supermarket and 油 means cooking oil.